# Variation norm and 1-Norm

Tags: measure-theory, total-variation

In a sigmafinite measure space (Ω, S, µ) with a finite signed measure ν i should show

[image]

I know what the definition of these two are but i have no idea how too prove it.

Comment: You should write this equation for better reception of your question. Now concerning the question, it looks odd that in your equation the left hand side does not depend on $\mu$ but the right hand side does. I guess that replacing $\mu$ by $2 \times \mu$ shows it cannot hold.

Comment: I have seen a lot of questions about the Total variation distance in relation to the Radon-Nikodym derivates. Isnt this the same just for the case that one of the two measures is zero?

Comment: and i dont know how to write mathematical equatuions on this website

Comment: To see how to use mathjack and how to ask a good question, see this thread and the references herein https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please consider replacing $\mu$ by $2 \times \mu$ and tell me what happens.

Comment: The RHS changes but the LHS doesnt. Or what do you mean?